# Why does "a@a" pass built-in validation for an email input?

Tags: html, validation

I created an input with the following mark-up:

```
<input name="contactEmail" type="email" required>
```

I added a CSS class for `input:invalid` which gives it a red border, and then tested it by inputting `a@a` as the value, and the field was marked valid. Why would that be a valid input for this when it's clearly not a valid email? Regarding valid values for an input of type `email`, [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email):

> In simple terms, this means username@domain.tld

But this obviously *doesn't* match any regex designed to look for that pattern. So...what gives?

**Edit:**

According to MDN, this is algorithm used for email validation in compliant browser:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

I haven't broken that apart yet, but `a@a` does indeed match it. So I guess the question becomes *why* does the regex all that to match?

Comment: [Can you have an email address with only the top level domain as the domain part?](https://serverfault.com/questions/721927/can-you-have-an-email-address-with-only-the-top-level-domain-as-the-domain-part/721929) and [New gTLD Dotless Domain Names Prohibited](https://www.icann.org/news/announcement-2013-08-30-en). So while it is valid to have `a@a` according to the specs, it is prohibited according to the icann. But because ICANN could change its mind in future, you would develop a validator according to the specs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hostnames do not have to have a domain associated with their TLD. A common example would be `localhost`.

Comment: `localhost` is a TLD ([rfc2606](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606)). But a TLD does not need to have the domain or subdomain part. So `a@com` could also be valid.

Comment: [Can you have an email address with only the top level domain as the domain part?](https://serverfault.com/questions/721927/can-you-have-an-email-address-with-only-the-top-level-domain-as-the-domain-part/721929)

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing invalid about it.  It's as simple as that.

There's no reason a mailbox can't be called `a` on the host `a`.